# How to delete files from a NAS drive in OSX

Tags: macos

I am running Mavericks on a 2012 Mac Mini.  I have a WD MyBookLive NAS drive on the network which appears under SHARED in Finder.  There are lots of files on the drive I want to delete but my Mac seems unable to do it.

When choosing Move to Trash, a progress bar pops up and stays there forever.

Comment: Trash only works on local files - try a direct delete

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: Interesting. Are you connecting to the NAS using SMB or AFP or some other protocol combination? I could see the .Trashes folder being a problem if the OS wants to move the files to be deleted rather than deleting them in place.

Comment: It is using AFP I believe.  OSX gives me the option of Move to Trash so I am surprised that it is not supposed to work.

Comment: If you are comfortable with Terminal, you can use `rm`.

Comment: Thanks.  In the end, I did use "rm".  It took hours to run but got the job done in the end.